# How to Convert a field with the following format dd/mm/yyyy into a valid datetime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am working on c# application, which reads data from a .csv file and populate our database.

now the .csv file contain the date information in the following format `dd/mm/yyyy` such as `22/07/2011`. so when I try adding this value inside our database using ado.net entity framework :-

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\csv\file01.csv");

parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
parser.SetDelimiters(",");


while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    Employee DBrecord = new Employee();
    DBrecord.LeavingDate = DateTime.Parse(CSVfields[49]);
```

I got the following exception :-

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

so can anyone advice on this please , how I can add my date with the following format `dd/mm/yyyy` inside the database ?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @SonerGönül the date I am reading is stored inside .csv ... you mean the culture for the database ? if yes then I have us_english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateString,
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

This basically tells the parser what format to expect.

Note that it's `MM` and not `mm` as one is months, the other is minutes.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but in my case the CSVfield[49] might be empty,, so the ParseExact will raise an exception ... do I need to check if the string is empty before calling ParseExact() ? or I can handle this without the check ?

Comment: Yes you'd have to check if it's empty.